# Dynamic circuit using second-order differential equation

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential, dynamic

For the past few weeks I have been trying to solve this dynamic circuit with no lock in solving the whole equation. I have difficulty in finding the contants at the end of the equation when coming up with the general solution for the circuit. Here is the question:
[image]

This is my note trying to solve it:

[image]
[image]

Correct me if my understanding of the way I have analyzed the circuit is incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to actually solve i.e. what is your end-goal?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm trying to solve i_L(t) posed by the question above.

Comment: Have you not learnt Laplace yet? BTW you need to have a citation for the image in your question.

Comment: @KondoAI I haven't yet looked over your work. That will have to wait until another time. But thanks for adding it here. I have a few questions... Are you supposed to solve this using a state variable approach? Laplace? Annihilators? Anything in particular? Meantime, [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/662662) may be of some help.

Comment: We haven't learned Laplace yet. The teacher requested us to use state variable.

Comment: \$i_L(t)\$ has two components, but you're only using one initial condition -- why aren't you taking the capacitor voltage at \$t = 0\$ into account?

Comment: @TimWescott why do we need to take the voltage of the capacitor at t = 0? I don't understand. Other people does that and did understand why.

Comment: What are the values of \$k_1\$ and \$k_2\$?  Do you need both to fully define \$i(t)\$?  Can you say what they are?  If not, why not?

Comment: 1/1.25µF = 800*10^3  with this large value you get a negative value under the root and thus 2 complex conjugate solutions. the complex solution represent the frequency with which the engery swings between L and C and is about 160Hz in your case. stich your exponentials together so that you combine them to real solutons that match the initial conditons (i(t=0)=0 and Uc(t=0)=U0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to find the free response of that system, with no use of Laplace Transform, is assuming a possible response (the exponential function is a good candidate due to its properties, like the derivative being similar to the function itself).

Applying the KVL in \$t = 0_+\$ (immediately after the switch is closed):

$$-R_2i_L(t)-L\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}-v_C(t)=0 \qquad (1)$$

Deriving wrt to time:

$$L\frac{d^2i_L(t)}{dt^2}+R_2\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}+\frac{dv_C(t)}{dt}=0$$

Replacing \$\frac{dv_C(t)}{dt}=\frac{i_L(t)}{C}\$

$$\frac{d^2i_L(t)}{dt^2}+\frac{R_2}{L}\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}+\frac{i_L(t)}{LC}=0$$

Replacing component values:

$$\frac{d^2i_L(t)}{dt^2}+750\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}+10^6i_L(t)=0 \qquad (2)$$

Assuming a possible solution as: \$i_L(t)=Ae^{st}\$ in \$(2)\$:

$$s^2Ae^{st}+750sAe^{st}+10^6Ae^{st}=0$$

$$Ae^{st}\left(s^2 +750s+10^6 \right )=0$$

Therefore, the characteristic equation is:

$$s^2 +750s+10^6=0$$

With complex conjugate roots:

$$
\begin{cases}
  s_1=\underbrace{-375}_{-\alpha}+j\underbrace{927.025}_{\omega_d=\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\alpha^2}}\\
\\
  s_2=-375-j927.025
\end{cases}
$$

Where:

$$
\begin{cases}
  \alpha=\frac{R_2}{2L}= 375 \space Np/s \\
  \omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}=1000 \space Hz \\
  \omega_d=927.025 \space Hz
\end{cases}
$$

As \$\omega_0>\alpha\$, the system is **underdamped** (the roots already indicated that).

For an underdamped RLC series circuit without source (drived only by the initial conditions), the response has the form:

$$i_L(t)={e^{-\alpha t}[ K_1\cos(\omega_d t)+ K_2\sin(\omega_d t)]}u(t) \qquad (3)$$

where \$u(t)\$ is the unit step function.

The initial conditions are:

$$
\begin{cases}
  i_L(0_+)=i_L(0_-)=0 \space A \\
  v_C(0_+)=v_C(0_-)=15 \space V \\
\end{cases}
$$

Doing \$t=0_+\$ in \$(3)\$:

$$K_1=i_L(0_+)=0$$

Doing \$t=0_+\$ in \$(1)\$:

$$-R_2i_L(0_+)-L\frac{di_L(0_+)}{dt}-v_C(0_+)=0$$

Resulting in:

$$\frac{di_L(0_+)}{dt}=-18.75 \space A/s$$

Deriving \$(3)\$ wrt time:

$$
\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}=-\alpha e^{-\alpha t}[K_1\cos(\omega_d t)+K_2\sin(\omega_d t)]+e^{-\alpha t}[-K_1\omega_d\sin(\omega_d t)+K_2\omega_d\cos(\omega_d t)]
$$

In \$t=0_+\$:

$$\frac{di_L(0_+)}{dt}=-\alpha K_1+K_2\omega_d=-18.75\qquad  A/s$$

With:

$$K_2=-0.0202$$

So, from \$(3)\$, the total response is:

$$\boxed{i_L(t)=[-0.0202e^{-375t}\sin(927.025t)]u(t)}$$

With plot:

[image]