# How to find a characteristic equation for the current response for this circuit?

Tags: passive-networks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source: Linear Circuits Time Domains, Phasor, and Laplace Transform Approaches Third Edition.
author: Raymond A. DeCarlo, Pen Min Lin
Publisher: Kendall Hunt Publishing Company

I suspect this solution is wrong in that it misuses the characteristic equation for Vc(t) for finding iL(t), as I am having trouble finding the second order differential equation for iL(t) and think which is impossible. I succeeded in finding the 2nd order equation for Vc(t) which is similar to the solution in the textbook.

My solution:

iin(t)-Vc(t)/R = iL(t) + CdVc(t)/dt, KCL

Finding Characteristic Equation:

iL(t) + CdVc(t)/dt + Vc(t)/R = 0

1/R * dVc(t)/dt + diL(t)/dt + C*(d^2 Vc(t)/dt^2) = 0

Since VL(t) = Vc(t) = L * di(t)/dt,

1/R * dVc(t)/dt + 1/L * Vc(t) + C*(d^2 Vc(t)/dt^2) = 0

...
Am I doing something wrong? How do I find the 2nd-order differential equation for iL(t) using something like KVL?

Comment: I'm busy today. But you might read [some of my scribbles here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/662662/330261). Not too distant from this.

Comment: Thanks, will look it up!

Comment: Took a moment. Luckily, was able to copy and paste a lot. So it wasn't as bad as I imagined.

Comment: Simple proof: The left side of the char. equation appears in the denominator of the transfer function - in this case: Z=V/I. This is nothing else than the complex impedance of the circuit.

Answer (score 3):

#### KCL

Grounding the bottom node, find this KCL for the top node (\$v\$):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{v}{R}+\frac1{L}\int v\:\text{d}t+C\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v+i_0&= 0\:\text{A}
\\\\
\frac{1}{R}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v+\frac1{L} v+C\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}v&= 0\:\frac{\text{A}}{\text{s}}
\\\\
\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}v+\frac{1}{R\,C}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v+\frac1{L\,C} v&= 0\:\frac{\text{A}}{\text{s}}
\\\\
\left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+\frac{1}{R\,C}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{L\,C}\right] v&= 0\:\frac{\text{A}}{\text{s}}
\end{align*}$$

So, the characteristic equation is pretty easy to spot there. It is \$s^2+\frac1{R\,C}s+\frac1{L\,C}\$, using \$s\$ as a derivative operator. And that's what they said it is, too.

#### time domain solution

The above is homogeneous and it's clear that no matter what \$v\$ may be that \$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+\frac{1}{R\,C}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{L\,C}\$ must cause it to become zero. In short, \$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+\frac{1}{R\,C}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{L\,C}\$ annihilates \$v\$.

It turns out that \$\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right)^2+\beta^2\right]^m\$ annihilates any solution of the general form: \$\quad f\left(t\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} t^k\,\exp\left(\alpha\,t\right)\left\{ A_{2k}\,\cos\left(\beta\,t\right) + A_{2k+1}\,\sin\left(\beta\,t\right)\right\}\$.

Recomposing \$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+\frac{1}{R\,C}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{L\,C}\$ into the form of \$\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right)^2+\beta^2\$ means that \$\alpha=\frac{-1}{2R\,C}\$ and \$\beta=\sqrt{\frac1{L\,C}-\frac1{4R^{\,2}\,C^{\,2}}}\$. This allows us to use the general solution form since we know that it is annihilated by this composition.

For case 1, \$\alpha=-10000\$ and \$\beta=\sqrt{39900000000}\$ and those values can be plugged into the general solution for \$v\$.

Initial conditions and derivatives can be used then to lock down the constants for the specific solution. And from there, the inductor current specific solution can fall out, too.

That's one way.

#### Laplace solution

Another is to apply Laplace:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}v+\frac{1}{R\,C}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v+\frac1{L\,C} v&= 0\:\text{A}
\\\\
\mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}v+\frac{1}{R\,C}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v+\frac1{L\,C} v\right\}&= \mathscr{L}\left\{0\:\text{A}\right\}
\\\\
\mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}v\right\}+\frac{1}{R\,C}\mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v\right\}+\frac1{L\,C}\mathscr{L}\left\{ v\right\}&= 0
\\\\
\left\{\vphantom{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}}s^2V-sv_{_0}-v_{_0}^{'}\right\}+\frac{1}{R\,C}\left\{\vphantom{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}}sV-v_{_0}\right\}+\frac1{L\,C}\left\{\vphantom{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}}V\right\}&= 0
\\\\
\left[s^2+\frac{1}{R\,C}s+\frac1{L\,C}\right]V&=\left(s+\frac{1}{R\,C}\right)v_{_0}+v_{_0}^{'}
\end{align*}$$

Since \$v_{_0}=0\:\text{V}\$ and the current supplied is \$i_0=1\:\text{A}\$, it's clear that \$v_{_0}^{'}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v_{_0}=\frac{i_{_0}-i_{_\text{L}\left(0\right)}}{C}=\frac{1\:\text{A}}{100\:\text{nF}}=1\times 10^7\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}}\$.

*(For Laplace, I'll henceforth drop the units in the equations except where it's important when identifying a component value.)*

For case 1, the above then becomes: \$\left[s^2+20000s+40000000000\right]V= 10000000\$. Solve for \$V\$ and perform the inverse Laplace and you have \$v_t\$. (And when you do, you will make use of \$\alpha=-10000\$ and \$\beta=\sqrt{39900000000}\$, again.)

That's another way.

Of course, that only gets you \$v_t\$. You need \$i_{_\text{L}\left(t\right)}\$.

#### inductor current

\$V=L \mathscr{L}\left\{i_{_\text{L}\left(t\right)}^{'}\right\}=L\left[s I_{_\text{L}}-i_{_\text{L}\left(0\right)}\right]\$. In this case, that simplifies to \$V=L s I_{_\text{L}}\$ as \$i_{_\text{L}\left(0\right)}=0\:\text{A}\$.

So, again for case 1, replacing \$V\$ find \$\left[s^2+20000s+40000000000\right]250\:\mu\text{H}\: s I_{_\text{L}}= 10000000\$. Solve for \$I_{_\text{L}}\$ and perform the inverse Laplace and you have \$i_{_\text{L}\left(t\right)}\$.

In this case there will, of course, be a need for \$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac1{s}\right\}\$, which is just the unit impulse. (And you know what that should be: \$i_{_0}\$.)

#### results

From either the time domain solution and working out the constants or from the Laplace process indicated above, the time domain results are:

$$\begin{align*}
v_t&=v_{_0}^{'}\:\exp\left(\alpha \,t\right)\:\frac{\sin\left(\beta\,t\right)}{\beta}
\\\\
i_{_\text{L}\left(t\right)}&=i_{_0}\left(1-\exp\left(\alpha \,t\right)\left[\cos\left(\beta\,t\right)-\alpha\:\frac{\sin\left(\beta\,t\right)}{\beta}\right]\right)
\end{align*}$$

Dimensional analysis also works out. \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$ are in units of \$\frac1{\text{s}}\$, \$v_{_0}^{'}\$ is in units of \$\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}}\$, and \$i_{_0}\$ is in units of \$\text{A}\$.

Finally, note that the above also works if \$i_{_0}=0\:\text{A}\$ at \$t=0\$, as this also implies that \$v_{_0}^{'}=0\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}}\$ (see earlier calculation for it), which results in zero for both functions (as it should be in that case.)

#### validation

I've plugged all this, the circuit and the mathematics, into LTspice and generated the outputs below:

[image]

Note the exact matches between simulation and my mathematical work above. *(Click on the image above to expand it.)*

#### summary

That about covers it.

There is a small detail. It's possible that \$\beta\$ is imaginary (over-damped cases.) In such cases, the sine and cosine functions are replaced with their hyperbolic versions and you move on.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't got to review Laplace transform yet. This exercise is just a preparation for my revision on Laplace transform. I am struggling to understand how to use Laplace transform to design an op-amp, any suggestions for this?

Comment: @TSLee I provided at the outset a non-Laplace  approach. I later use Laplace. But that doesn't negate the earlier exposition. I left some work to do. But led the way. Do you need that approach expanded, solving for the same constants I find with Laplace? Or can you handle things from where i left it and use initial conditions to find those same values?

Comment: I figure out the time domain equation for the inductor current. Then the equation leads me to the solution same as the one in textbook. For the solution in Laplace transform, I need some time to follow up.

Comment: @TSLee Well, I think you see the textbook is wrong. And if you agree with it in your own result that is the same, then there is a problem. I have three reasons for being sure: (1) The Laplace answer confirms it; and, (2) The Spice simulation confirms it; and, (3) I'm tentatively confident in my work product.

Comment: I am trying to follow the steps for the solution of Laplace transform. Where did the s go when you found V' which is (1*10^7 V)/s?

Comment: @TSLee If I understand your question, then the right side of the equation is: \$\left(s+\frac{1}{R\,C}\right)v_{_0}+v_{_0}^{'}\$. There is no `s` associated with \$v_{_0}^{'}\$.  \$v_{_0}^{'}\$ is a simple constant that must be evaluated at \$t=0\$. \$v_{_0}\$ does have an `s` associated with it, but since \$v_{_0}=0\$ at \$t=0\$ that entire term disappears. So the focus is only on the value for  \$v_{_0}^{'}\$ at \$t=0\$. Through all these discussions, keep firmly in mind that Spice itself confirms the results. You cannot escape that experimental result. It reproduces what I've shown.

Comment: I think I am confused about a constant and u(t). Since V’(0) = a constant value, I thought if we do a Laplace transform on V’(0), V’(0) = (1/s)*some value.

Comment: My silly mistake, as t = 0 and this is not a constant value*u(t), Laplace transform of V’(0) must be constant.

Comment: @TSLee Glad to hear my writing isn't a complete fail at communication. ;)

Comment: I just posted my solution. Please let me know if you find any errors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems very odd to me. The final equation of the inductor current has a positive e term. Which means the inductor current right when the source turns on draws 1 + the e function. Here is the functions graph.
[image]

From analysis we know that the inductor current iL(0-) = iL(0+) because inductor current cant change instantaneously. So that must be wrong for a start. If the e term was negative it would make a little more sense.

For parallel RLC circuits with switching sources you find the transient response and the steady state response:

Vc(t)= Vtransient(t) + Vss(t).

You have to find voltage first because trying KVL on a parallel RLC circuit will not give you a workable differential equation. For the transient response you take out all independent sources. The switching source is independent because it does not rely on current or voltage from somewhere else. Only once you have got the above equation you start finding your constants with your initial values.

There are better ways to find the inductor current for parallel RLC circuits. You can first find the parallel voltage Vc(t). Then you simply substitute it into the inductor equation. Do some algebra. Then you will have to integrate(not nice).

V = L*di/dt

Better way is to use KCL now with your Vc(t) equation.

1A = Vc(t)/R + iL(t) + C*dv/dt

Rearrange the terms and now you only have to differentiate. A lot easier.

iL(t) = 1 - Vc(t)/R - C*dv/dt

Comment: Thanks, the first question that came to my mind was how I could miss the rearrangement for the equation to get to the iL(t) expression. You are right, the textbook solution doesn't make sense that iL(t) at t = 0 should start from 0 and can't be instantaneously at some value. The 2nd-order equation of the solution should be iL(t) = 1/C - 1/RC * dVc(t)/dt - d^2 Vc/dt^2. Will update my solution soon.

Comment: @TSLee If you believe what you wrote, that *"the textbook solution doesn't make sense that iL(t) at t = 0 should start from 0"*, then there's no point updating your solution. It will be wrong. They get to tell you what it starts at, as the inductor may have any arbitrary, specified value at \$t=0\$. Just as the voltage difference across the capacitor may ***also*** have any arbitrary, specified value at \$t=0\$. They both can individually be anything they want them to be at \$t=0\$ and it's still all valid and works.

Comment: @periblepsis I read the question again. The question has given an initial condition that iL(0) = 0, Vc(0) = 0. Does it infer the values of the capacitor and inductor are constant?

Comment: @TSLee It only says what the values are at t=0. Not at other times. But you don't get to disagree and decide the author of the problem is mistaken as Gideon seems to imagine. They are both zero at t=0. And if your solution does not confirm it, then your solution fails. My solution is consistent with the problem statement.

Comment: @periblepsis ok, I get what you meant. What do you think about the final answer given by the textbook? It isn't consistent with the initial condition. iL(0) = sth* cos(2.866) + 1 does not equal to zero at t = 0.

Comment: @TSLee Well, textbooks are often produced initially by talented folks but then later editions are improved by students of various grades. In some cases, I've seen absolute garbage in the 9th or 11th edition of electronics textbooks. Enough that I'd just throw them away. I suspect a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed with @periblesis's solution of Laplace transform for VL, let's elaborate on the Laplace transform of IL(t) to the system response for IL(t) in the time domain.

VL(t) = Vc(t) = L*iL'(t)

Vc(s) = L*laplace transform{L*iL'(t)}

Vc(s) = L*(s*iL(s)-iL(0))

(1times10^7)/(s^2+20000s+4times10^10) = L*s*iL(s), iL(0) = 0

(1times10^7)/(0.25m*s)(s^2+20000s+4times10^10) = iL(s)

iL(s) = (4times10^10)/(s)(s^2+20000s+4times10^10)

iL(s) = (4times10^10)/[(s)(s+10000-j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2))(s+10000+j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2))]

= K1/s + K2/(s+10000-j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2)) + K3/(s+10000+j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2))

Partial Fraction:

1. sub s = 0 and get iL(s)*s to find K1.
2. Sub s = -10000 + j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2) and get iL(s)*(s+10000-j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2)) to find K2.
3. Sub s = -10000 - j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2) and get iL(s)*(s+10000+j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2)) to find K3.

Then, K1 = 1, K2 = -0.5 + j*(0.025031308) = 0.5exp(177.13 degree), and K3 = -0.5 + j*(0.025031308) = 0.5exp(-177.13 degree).

Therefore,

iL(s) = 1/s + 0.5exp(177.13 degree)/(s+10000-j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2)) + 0.5exp(-177.13 degree)/(s+10000+j*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2))

= 1 + 0.5*exp(-1000t) * 2cos(t*(sqrt(1.596*10^11)/2) + 177.13)

iL(0) = -0.99749

*This is a hand-written solution. I guess iL(0) is supposed to be zero if my solution is done by software,

Time domain method:

I found the KCL first, and then substituted Vc(t) = L*diL(t)/dt.

*My solution was the same as the textbook's. What will be the difference if I find Vc(t)'s response first, and then elaborate on it to find iL(t)? The Laplace transform method makes more sense. What's wrong with this time domain method?